# Simple Big O questions

Tags: time-complexity

4. Hash table (array list for overflow handling)

a. Find O( )

b. Insert  O( )

c. Ascend (print values sorted in ascending order)  O( )

5. Binary Search Tree

a. Delete  O( )

b. Ascend (print values sorted in ascending order)  O( )

**My answer:**
4. a. Find has to be O(n) since overflow can potentially cause it to go through the entire hashmap

b. same as a, O(n)

c. My guess here is O(nlogn) since it can use some kind of heap sort to sort and printing is just n, so n+nlogn = nlogn

5. a. O(n) just because I remember this from the book

b. my guess is the same as question 4, nlogn since heapsort can be used

I'm I correct? 
Thanks!

Comment: stackoverflow is not a homework service! Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what questions are appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its hard to answer this without a bit more contextual information, however usually for hash tables find and insert are O(1).

So my answers would be:

4a. O(1)

4b. O(1)

4c. O(n log n)

5a. O(log n)

5b. O(n log n)